# Ionic and Angular: Routing not working

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have an Ionic sidemenu project with the following menu:

```
<ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="false">
    <ion-side-menu-content>
        <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable" align-title="center">
            <ion-nav-back-button>
            </ion-nav-back-button>

            <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
                <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left">
                </button>
            </ion-nav-buttons>
        </ion-nav-bar>
        <ion-nav-view name="menuContent"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-side-menu-content>

    <ion-side-menu side="left">
        <ion-content>
            <div class="list">
                <a class="item item-icon-left" menu-close href="#/app/products">
                    <i class="icon ion-home"></i>
                    <h2>Home</h2>
                </a>
                <a class="item item-icon-left" menu-close href="#/app/account">
                    <i class="icon ion-person"></i>
                    <h2>mein Konto</h2>
                </a>
                <a class="item item-icon-left" menu-close href="#/app/orders">
                    <i class="icon ion-android-list"></i>
                    <h2>meine Bestellungen</h2>
                </a>
            </div>
        </ion-content>
    </ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>
```

The hrefs defined here are all working as intended.

My products page now has several sub-pages.

Html-File:

```
<ion-view view-title="Home">
    <ion-content>
        <ion-list>
            <ion-item ng-repeat="product in products" href="#/app/products/{{product.templateUrl}}">
                {{product.name}}
            </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

JS-File:

```
angular.module('App.Products', ['App.Products.Prints', 'App.Products.Box', 'App.Products.Book', 'App.Products.Framed'])

.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('app.products', {
        url: "/products",
        views: {
            'menuContent': {
                templateUrl: "modules/products/products.html",
                controller: 'ProductsController'
            }
        }
    });
})

.controller('ProductsController', function ($scope, ProductsFactory) {
    $scope.products = [];

    init();

    function init() {
        $scope.products = ProductsFactory.getProducts();
    }
})

.factory('ProductsFactory', function() {
    var products = [
        {
            name: 'Prints',
            img: 'img/wardwarz.png',
            templateUrl: 'prints'
        },
        {
            name: 'PhotoBox',
            img: 'img/argo.png',
            templateUrl: 'box'
        },
        {
            name: 'Photobuch',
            img: 'img/django.png',
            templateUrl: 'book'
        },
        {
            name: 'Photo im Rahmen',
            img: 'img/ic_profile.png',
            templateUrl: 'framed'
        }
    ];

    var factory = {};

    factory.getProducts = function () {
        // Hier könnte ein HTTP Request rein um die Produkte vom Server zu erhalten!

        return products;
    }

    return factory;
});
```

and to show one example one content of a sub page:

Html-File:

```
<ion-view view-title="Prints">
    <ion-content>

    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

JS-File:

```
angular.module('App.Products.Prints', [])

.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('app.products.prints', {
        url: "/products/prints",
        views: {
            'menuContent': {
                templateUrl: "modules/products/prints/prints.html"
            }
        }
    });
});
```

When i now start the app `ionic serve` the navigation of the sidemenu works fine and i can open my products page. The navigation to `prodcuts/prints` does not work. I dont get an error message or anything. There is just nothing happening after the click on the item.

Whats going worng here?

An example Project can be found here: [Mega File - MyApp.rar](http://www.megafileupload.com/1ZRf/myApp.rar)

Comment: Have you tried href="#/products/{{product.templateUrl}}"

Comment: yes. same behaviour. no error. no 404. no cant find source. its just doing nothing.

Comment: Could you make a jsfiddle please ?

Comment: since i have no idea how to work with jsfiddle i uploaded a sample project here: http://www.megafileupload.com/1ZRf/myApp.rar

Comment: cant figure out whats the problem. i get an error if the url isnt correct. i get no error in my project so the pathes should be correct. I really dont get why the routing isnt working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using only href to do your navigation use

```
ui-sref="name_of_the_state"
```

Example:

```
ui-sref="app.products.prints"
```

This way you will not have issues with your navigation on angular/ionic.

If you even have a parameter in your route, like:

```
$stateProvider.state('app.products.edit', {
    url: "/products/edit/:id",
    views: {
        'menuContent': {
            templateUrl: "modules/products/prints/prints.html"
        }
    }
});
```

you can use:

```
ui-sref="app.products.edit(1)"
```

Also, I'm not seeying an abstract route on this, the app. It should be like:

```
app -> abstract
app.products
app.products.prints
```

I was able to simulate the error on my PC.
When you work with nested states you like app.products.print you need a intermediary view like this:

Example from a code I have on my pc that is working:

```
.state("admin", {
                url: "/admin",
                abstract: true,
                views: {
                    "body": { templateUrl: "partials/_layoutAdmin.html" }
                }
            })
            .state("admin.page", {
                url: "/page/:idEdition",
                abstract: true,
                views: {
                    "header": { templateUrl: "partials/header.html", controller: "DefaultHeaderController" },
                    "content": { templateUrl: "partials/_layoutAdminEdition.html" }
                }
            })
            .state("admin.page.create", {
                url: "/create",
                views: {
                    "content": { templateUrl: "partials/admin.page.form.html", controller: "PageFormController" }
                }
            })
```

Example of Templates

The main layout has thi

```
<div data-ui-view="body"></div>
```

The _layoutAdmin has this one

```
<header data-ui-view="header"></header>



<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div data-ui-view="content"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When the code enters the admin state it will load this first piece...

THEN...

```
<div data-ui-view="content" class="edition-form"></div>
```

AND THEN... the form CODE

So, in your case, you have app.products.prints:

app -> need a view -> ok you got it

app.products -> also need a view -> ok you got it

app.products.prints -> inside app.products view (products.html) you need a  to show this inside it.

For simplicity, I suggest you to change it's name to app.productsPrint (without the "." and you'll be able to do it the way you are doing it right now with no impact.

---

Made some changes on the code you provided:

```
<ion-view view-title="Home">
    <ion-content>
        <div ui-view="myTestContent"></div>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Notice the **ui-view="myTestContent"**

and

```
.state('app.products.prints', {
        url: "/prints",
        views: {
            'myTestContent': {
                templateUrl: "modules/products/prints/prints.html"
            }
        }
    });
```

and it worked.

So, in your case I recommend you to use productPrints instead of products.print. This nesting is used in those view inside view scenarios.

Comment: same behaviour with ui-sref.

Comment: do you have an app abstract state on your route list?

Comment: yes i have: `$stateProvider.state('app', {
        url: "/app",
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: "modules/menu/menu.html",
    });`

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your help. I could not get your example with `<div ui-view="myTestContent"></div>` working but changing the state from `app.products.prints` to `app.prints` worked very good. thank you.

Comment: @PedroMatos The ui-sref syntax only works for me like this `ui-sref="app.products.edit({ id: 1 })"`